# Removing specific string from array

Tags: arrays, powershell

I have the following result from my PowerShell script:

```
SQLINST15    : MSSQL11.SQLINST15
SQLINST16    : MSSQL12.SQLINST16
SQLINST17    : MSSQL12.SQLINST17
SQLINST18    : MSSQL12.SQLINST18
SQLINST19    : MSSQL13.SQLINST19
SQLINST20    : MSSQL13.SQLINST20
SQLINST13    : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST13
SQLINST1     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST1
SQLINST2     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST2
SQLINST3     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST3
SQLINST4     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST4
SQLINST5     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST5
SQLINST6     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST6
SQLINST21    : MSSQL12.SQLINST21
```

And i'm trying to remove all strings containing `SQLINST%Number%    :` Or before Colon (included) the so that in the end my array (`$SQLNamedInstanceArray`) will be as follows:

```
MSSQL11.SQLINST15
MSSQL12.SQLINST16
MSSQL12.SQLINST17
MSSQL12.SQLINST18
MSSQL13.SQLINST19
MSSQL13.SQLINST20
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST13
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST1
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST2
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST3
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST4
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST5
MSSQL10_50.SQLINST6
MSSQL12.SQLINST2
```

This is my current PowerShell code:

```
$RegistrySQLPath = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'
Set-Location $RegistrySQLPath
$SQLNamedInstanceArray = (Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistrySQLPath | Out-String) -split "`r`n" | Select-String MSSQL
$SQLNamedInstanceArray
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like regex match:

```
$SQLNamedInstanceArray = "SQLINST15    : MSSQL11.SQLINST15",
"SQLINST16    : MSSQL12.SQLINST16",
"SQLINST17    : MSSQL12.SQLINST17",
"SQLINST18    : MSSQL12.SQLINST18",
"SQLINST19    : MSSQL13.SQLINST19",
"SQLINST20    : MSSQL13.SQLINST20",
"SQLINST13    : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST13",
"SQLINST1     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST1",
"SQLINST2     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST2",
"SQLINST3     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST3",
"SQLINST4     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST4",
"SQLINST5     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST5",
"SQLINST6     : MSSQL10_50.SQLINST6",
"SQLINST21    : MSSQL12.SQLINST21"

$SQLNamedInstanceArray | % { [Regex]::Match($_, '(?<=: ).*').Value }
```

Comment: i need to put $src in a for each condition (for every line in my array)?

Comment: `Regex` should be applied to every line.

Comment: the regex works, but now i'm getting duplicate values. `foreach($SQLNamedInstanc in $SQLNamedInstanceArray){
$SQLNamedInstanceArray | % { [Regex]::Match($_, '(?<=: ).*').Value }
}`

Comment: I misunderstood - you have to iterate over every line - that's what `%` is for. Edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Don't convert your registry data to a string in the first place, since that usually only complicates matters. It's far easier to extract the value from the original registry data.

Remove the `PS*` properties from the registry child items so that you only get the registry values with the instance names. Then use the intrinsic property `PSObject` to expand the values of the remaining object properties.

```
$exclude = 'PSPath', 'PSParentPath', 'PSChildName', 'PSDrive', 'PSProvider'
Get-ItemProperty -Path $RegistrySQLPath |
    Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty $exclude |
    ForEach-Object { $_.PSObject.Properties.Value }
```

Comment: Thank! that's what i wanted to achieve from the first place, but didn't know how to accomplish that.. can you please explain about the intrinsic *property PSObject*? cause i'm trying to understand the last line of you code, without any success so far..

Comment: All PowerShell objects have a hidden property `PSObject` that (among other things) allows you to enumerate the properties of the object. You can see the hidden properties when using [`Get-Member`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-member?view=powershell-3.0) with the parameter `-Force`.